# Replicate the SQL Join using List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, inner-join

Is it possible to replicate your SQL Join using `List<T>`? I'm somehow distancing myself from the use of the DataTable and DataSet and trying to replicate it using the List.

Comment: That's what you have the `SelectMany` linq-method for.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. AFAIK, you can use any LINQ operator (including `join`) for in-memory data like `List`.

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ, you can *almost* just copy what you would have written in SQL. :)

Something like this:

```
List<T> foo = ...;
List<U> bar = ...;

var query = from f in foo
            join b in bar on f.x = b.x
            select new { f, b };

foreach (var q in query) { ... }
```